# Is it possible to pass twig variables into templates?

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I'm using the Timber plugin for my Wordpress site. For a little button component, i'm trying to pass the variable `{{ site.link }}` to use as my href.

Like so:

```
{% include 'component/icon-button.twig' with { href: '{{ site.theme.link }}/faq' } %}
```

icon-button.twig

```
<button class="icon-button" data-href="{{ href }}">text</button>
```

But that only results in `{{ site.link }}/faq` being output as is, as a string, not the actual URL.

How would i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just because when you use include in twig you don't need to use double {{ again. The correct syntax would be:

```
{% include 'component/icon-button.twig' with { href: site.theme.link ~ '/faq' } %}
```

The "~" is used for string concatenation in twig. You were passing the whole thing as a string and nothing more =)

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank mate.